# Prove that there exists a non-zero vector $v \in V$ such that $v \perp U$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\DeclareMathOperator{\dim}{dim}$In Euclidean space $(X,\left\langle \cdot , \cdot \right\rangle )$ where $\dim X < \infty$. Suppose we have two subspaces $U,V \subset X$ and $\dim U<\dim V$. Prove that there exists a non-zero vector $v \in V$ such that $v \perp U$.

I tried to do this task however I don't have any idea how to prove it because I have less information about $U$ and I cannot even use the condition for the perpendicularity of vectors because it does not give me anything.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be the orthogonal projection on $U$, since $dimU <dim V$,  the kernel of the restriction of $p$ to $V$ is not zero ($dim V=dim ker p_{\mid V}+dim Imp_{\mid V}$ since $dim Imp_{\mid V}<dim U$  this implies that $dim kerp_{\mid V}>0$ since $dimU<dim V$), there exists $v\in V$ such that $p(v)=0$, this implies that $v$ is orthogonal to $U$.

Answer (score 2):

We have that $U^\perp$ is a subspace of $X$ whose codimension is $\dim(U)$, while the codimension of $V$ is $\dim(X) - \dim(V)$.  Since the sum of these two codimensions is $\dim(X) - \dim(V) + \dim(U) < \dim(X)$, it follows that $U^\perp \cap V$ is not the trivial subspace.  Therefore, if you take a nonzero member $v \in U^\perp \cap V$, then $v \in V$ and $v$ is orthogonal to $U$.

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat more concrete way to see this is as follows:

since

$\dim X < \infty, \tag 1$

we have

$\dim U < \infty \tag 2$

as well; let

$\vec e_i \in U, \; 1 \le i \le \dim U, \tag 3$

be an orthonormal basis (for $U$, of course).  For $\vec x \in X$ define

$P\vec x = \displaystyle \sum_1^{\dim U} \langle \vec x, \vec e_i \rangle \vec e_i; \tag 4$

it is easy to see that

$P:X \to U \tag 5$

is a linear map; also, for

$\vec y \in U, \tag 6$

we have

$\vec y = \displaystyle \sum_1^{\dim U} \langle \vec y, \vec e_i \rangle \vec e_i, \tag 7$

thus, since $\langle \vec e_i, \vec e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$,

$P\vec y = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^{\dim U} \left \langle \sum_{j = 1}^{\dim U} \langle \vec y, \vec e_j \rangle \vec e_j, \vec e_i \right \rangle \vec e_i = \sum_1^{\dim U} \langle \vec y, \vec e_i \rangle \vec e_i = \vec y; \tag 8$

that is, $P$ fixes $U$, element-wise.  Thus, in light of (5),

$\vec x \in X \Longrightarrow P^2 \vec x = P(P \vec x) = P \vec x, \tag 9$

i.e.,

$P^2 = P, \tag{10}$

a projection operator on $X$, with range $U$; a projection onto $U$.  Furthermore, it is also easy to see that $P$ is self-adjoint, that is,

$\vec x, \vec y \in X \Longrightarrow \langle P \vec x, \vec y \rangle = \langle \vec x, P \vec y \rangle; \tag{11}$

indeed,

$\langle P \vec x, \vec y \rangle = \left \langle \displaystyle \sum_1^{\dim U} \langle \vec x, \vec e_j \rangle  \vec e_j, \vec y \right \rangle =  \displaystyle \sum_1^{\dim U} \langle \vec x, \vec e_j \rangle \langle \vec e_j, \vec y \rangle = \sum_1^{\dim U} \langle \vec e_j, \vec y \rangle \langle \vec x, \vec e_j \rangle$
$= \displaystyle \sum_1^{\dim U} \langle \vec y, \vec e_j \rangle \langle \vec e_j, \vec x \rangle = \left \langle \displaystyle \sum_1^{\dim U} \langle \vec y, \vec e_j \rangle  \vec e_j, \vec x \right \rangle = \langle P\vec y, \vec x \rangle = \langle \vec x, P\vec y \rangle; \tag{12}$

now with (10) and (11) in hand we may resolve the primary question as follows:  since $\dim U < \dim V$ we may choose

$\vec v \in V \setminus U; \tag{13}$

then since

$\vec v \notin U, \tag{14}$

it follows that

$\vec v \ne P \vec v \in U; \tag{15}$

thus

$\vec v - P\vec v \ne 0; \tag{16}$

also,

$\vec u \in U \Longrightarrow \langle \vec u, \vec v - P\vec v \rangle = \langle \vec u, \vec v \rangle - \langle \vec u, P \vec v \rangle = \langle \vec u, \vec v \rangle - \langle P \vec u,\vec v \rangle = \langle \vec u, \vec v \rangle - \langle \vec u, \vec v \rangle = 0, \tag{17}$

and we conclude that

$0 \ne \vec v - P \vec v \in U^\bot \tag{18}$

as required.